# Parse multilevel JSON String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I want to parse the following JSON string in Javascript:

```
str = {
    "weather":[{
        "id":803,
        "main":"Clouds",
        "description":"broken clouds",
        "icon":"04d"
    }],
    "cod":200
}
```

I normally parse JSON strings like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
alert(obj.weather.description);
```

But in this case it doesn't work for me. How do I have parse such JSON strings?

Comment: This is not a JSON string, this is an object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: If you have problems understanding the structure after parsing, assign it to a global variable and then play with it in console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use

```
alert(str.weather[0].description);
```

1. As `str` is already an object, you don't need to `parse()` it again, this will result in an error.
2. Since `weather` is an array, You need to use `index` to access array's element.

Comment: The solution is, that weather is an array. Your anwser solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array like this:

```
alert(str.weather[0].description);
```